# JavaScript addEventListener why does it not bubble here?

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

AFAIK using a click event and the `addEventListener()` should bubble from the innermost element up to the outermost parent element. So what's wrong with the following code?

```js
function ChangeBackground(e){
  e.target.style.background = "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*256)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*256)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*256)+")";
}

var all= document.querySelectorAll("div,span,p");
for(var i=0; i<all.length;i++){
  all[i].addEventListener("click",ChangeBackground);
}
```

```css
div, span, p{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span>span
  <div>div
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <p>p</p>
</span>
<div>div
  <div>div
   <div>div</div>
  </div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```

When I click on the `p`, it does not change the background of its parent elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does bubble. The problem is in the handler where I referred to the `e.target` instead of `this`. Heres the corrected code snippet:

(Note that the default background is transparent.)

```js
function ChangeBackground(e){
  this.style.background = "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*256)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*256)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*256)+")";
}

var all= document.querySelectorAll("div,span,p");
for(var i=0; i<all.length;i++){
  all[i].addEventListener("click",ChangeBackground,false);
}
```

```css
div, span, p{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span>span
  <div>div
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <p>p</p>
</span>
<div>div
  <div>div
   <div>div</div>
  </div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```